# Não estou conseguindo acomodar três images em linha

Tags: css

Estou tentando deixar três imagens por linha em uma página, defini isso no corpo da página:

```
        <div class="produtos-ponta">
      <div class="produtos-conteudo-ponta one-fourth-ponta"><img class="photo" src="imagens-ponta/amsterdam.jpg"/>
        <div class="content">
          <h4 class="name">Descricao</h4>              
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="produtos-conteudo-ponta one-fourth-ponta"><img class="photo" src="imagens-ponta/arezzo.jpg"/>
        <div class="content">
          <h4 class="name">Descricao</h4>              
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="produtos-conteudo-ponta one-fourth-ponta"><img class="photo" src="imagens-ponta/belmont.jpg"  />
        <div class="content">
          <h4 class="name">Descricao</h4>              
        </div>
      </div>                    
    </div>
```

E isso no meu css:

```
.produtos-conteudo-ponta {
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 320px;
    float:left;
}

.produtos-conteudo-ponta .photo {   
    max-width:320px;
    max-height:196px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;   
}

.produtos-ponta {
    position:relative;
}

.one-fourth-ponta {
    width: 20.5%;   
    max-width: 320px;
}
```

Mas as imagens quebram a linha, gostaria de deixa-las em somente uma.

A página para visualização é essa:
[Página](http://moveissaobento.com.br/ponta-estoque2.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta adicionar `display: inline-block;` à class: `produtos-conteudo-ponta`

```
.produtos-conteudo-ponta {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

---

## Atualização

Para adicionar um espaçamento maior entre as imagem podes utilizar a propriedade - [**`margin`**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp). Como por exemplo `margin-left:10px;` ou `margin-right:10px;`. Ou mesmo adicionar ambos de maneira a que elas fiquem mais ou menos com uma margem igual para os dois lados.
No entanto eu abordaria isto de maneira diferente.

Como temos 3 `divs` em linha (inline), eu iria fazer o seguinte calculo:

> **100** a **dividir** por **3** que dá = `33.333333`
>   Este calculo será - `100%` o tamanho da `div parent` a dividir por `3 divs child`

então o tamanho da largura para a class `produtos-conteudo-ponta` será de `33.333333%` fazendo-as assim iguais do mesmo tamanho, e responsivas à `div parente`.
(isto pensando já na possibilidade de esta poder ser redimensionada mais tarde em ecrãs de pequenas resoluções)

```
.produtos-conteudo-ponta {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.333333%;
}
```

Em seguida iria modificar a hierarquia do código de marcação HTML da seguinte maneira:

```
<div class="produtos-conteudo-ponta one-fourth-ponta">
    <div class="content">
        <img class="photo" src="/imagens-ponta/amsterdam.jpg"/>
        <h4 class="name">Descricao</h4>              
    </div>
</div>
```

No código acima modificamos a imagem para ser incluída dentro da class `.content` pela seguinte razão:

Em vez de estarmos a mudar `class` por `class` e adicionar atributos a cada uma delas, como por exemplo - margens, espaçamentos etc vezes e vezes sem conta, em vez disso iremos apenas aplicar os estilos à class `.content`:

```
.content {
    display: block;     /* Poderíamos adicionar também width:100%; mas ao adicionarmos este atributo o width:100%; já está a ser aplicado */
    max-width: 200px;   /* Isto especifica que nós não queremos que a div cresça mais do que os 200px */
    margin: 0 auto;     /* Isto centraliza a div ao centro por igual - para ambos, a margem esquerda e a margem direita. É nesessário o display:block; acima já adicionado para que isto funcione correctamente */
}
.photo {width: 100%;}   /* E por fim a imagem ficará a 100% da div "content". que neste caso será o máximo de 200px */
```

### Eis um exemplo online disto no jsFiddle ► http://jsfiddle.net/hwjvnzgm

Arraste a janela de exibição do jsFiddle para ver o seu comportamento em várias resoluções.
Para aumentar ou diminuir o espaçamento entre elas basta ir brincando com o valor `max-width:200px;`

Comment: Nem lembrei do display: inline-block; +1

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, ficou muito bom.

Comment: Como posso deixar um espaçamento maior entre as imagens?

Comment: Atualizei a minha resposta @adventistapr , dê lá uma olhada :)

Comment: Olá @Chun obrigado pela atualização da resposta, prática e eficiente e me ajudou muito.

Answer (score 2):

Faça o teste com este css:

```
.produtos-conteudo-ponta{
    float:left
}
```

Ele faz com que todos os elementos de classe `.produtos-conteudo-ponta` flutuem a esquerda, assim os `Bloquinhos` ficaram lado a lado.

Como dito acima o efeito também pode ser alcançado com `display: inline-block;`

Fiddle: [Link para ver online](http://jsfiddle.net/51gujoqq/)

Comment: Obrigado @ricardo, foi de grande ajuda a sua dica,